# Set the layers style programmatically using QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2, qgis-processing

I have a layer of GPS points (about 60 layers) loaded inside my .qgs file.
I want to set all their styles in the same manner using a .qml file without doing it one by one.

Can somebody illustrate initial Python code to do this? I'm relatively new to QGIS (2.16.1 Nodebo) since I came from ArcGIS doing simple batch processing through arcpy. In arcpy, I call the arcpy.mapping module to access my .mxd file and update my layer style through UpdateLayer function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    layer.loadNamedStyle('path/to/qml/file')
```

Or if this won't work, try:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.loadNamedStyle('path/to/qml/file')
```

Comment: `for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():` does not work for me, instead I use `for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():`. Does it work for you? I'm using QGIS 2.16.

Comment: @Joseph: Both solutions work for me. (v. QGIS 2.14).

Comment: Interesting, tested again on 2.14.3 and still nothing. But I believe you as I have used that before ;)

Comment: I updated my post and now there are both solutions.

Comment: For me on QGIS 2.14.6 also works only second solution

Answer (score 5):

Not directly python solution, but there is a plugin called **MultiQml** that is exactly doing what you are looking for. After installing you find the plugin in menu *Plugins --> MultiQml --> MultiQml*. In plugin window select layers, click on *Apply style ...* button and search for your .qml file.

[image]